# AJAX запрос возвращает ошибку 403

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, ajax

при AJAX запросе:

```
$('.form__blue-button').on('click', function () {
        let ajaxscript = {
            ajax_url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'
        }
        let newUserEmail = $('#user__email').val()
        let newUserPassword = 'pqnc128Jdn'
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: ajaxscript.ajax_url,
            data: { 
                action: 'ajaxlogin', //calls wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlogin
                email: newUserEmail, 
                password: newUserPassword, 
            },
            success: function(data){
                $('form#login p.status').text(data.message);
                if (data.loggedin == true){
                    document.location.href = ajax_login_object.redirecturl;
                }
            },
            error: function(results){
                console.log(results)
            }
        });
        
    })
```

в функцию PHP:

```
function ajax_login_init(){

    wp_register_script('ajax-login-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/ajax-login-script.js', array('jquery') ); 
    wp_enqueue_script('ajax-login-script');

    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-login-script', 'ajax_login_object', array( 
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        'redirecturl' => home_url(),
        'loadingmessage' => __('Sending user info, please wait...')
    ));
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlogin', 'ajax_login' );
}

if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
    add_action('init', 'ajax_login_init');
}


function ajax_login(){

    check_ajax_referer( 'ajax-login-nonce', 'security' );

    $info = array();
    $info['user_login'] = $_POST['username'];
    $info['user_password'] = $_POST['password'];
    $info['remember'] = true;

    $user_signon = wp_signon( $info, false );
    if ( is_wp_error($user_signon) ){
        echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>false, 'message'=>__('Wrong username or password.')));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>true, 'message'=>__('Login successful, redirecting...')));
    }

    die();
}
```

Сервер возвращает ошибку 403

Уточню, код отвечает за логин юзера, плагинов кеширования нету, самого кеширования тоже

Comment: 403 -- ошибка значит что доступ запрещен, так как у Вас используется `check_ajax_referer()` скорее всего Вы не отправляете соответсвующее nonce поле. Убедиться в этом можно закомментировав этот самый `check_ajax_referer( 'ajax-login-nonce', 'security' )`.

Comment: @Simon, помогло, спасибо

Comment: Эй, минуточку! :)  Он там не просто так, это безопасность, а вы дырку сделали.

Comment: Ну, мой комментарий все же предполагал, что этот кусочек будет закомментирован только для того чтобы проверить, что причина именно в этом) И в случае если так, то все же передать nonce в запросе)

Comment: @Simon, можем с Вами связаться по почте? если да, то я оставлю свою почту